# adding class to an element via jQuery .live or .delegate

Tags: jquery, events, live, addclass

hi everyone: I'm trying to add a class via jquery .live to an ajaxed element using .load but with mouse action depending events I cant find the right solution. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, i you want good answers, you need to build complete questions... For instance, tell us what you are really doing, give us some code, which mouse event ? and that's the least you should give if you want some tips

Answer (score 1):

`.live()` and `.delegate()` can't be used to run arbitrary code when a new element is added.

They're meant specifically for handling events.

If you want to modify the elements, you need to select them from the DOM, or use a direct reference to the new elements before you add them to the DOM.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/some/path/',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function( d ) {
        var els = $( d );
        els.find('div').addClass('newClass');
        els.appendTo('body');
    }
});
```